# Twitter authentication in a desktop application

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working on a desktop app that works on a Twitter account. It is coded in C#/WinForms.

I have created a Twitter account and an application in it. In this way I have all tokens necessary for the authentication. My application works nice using twitter API and passing the tokens to it.

I want to start a user stream on a Twitter account knowing only username and password.
Sending the username and password to Twitter, can I receive back the tokens for the authentication? How can I do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com)' corresponding documentation for this : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens. The first link is for "Sign in with Twitter" for websites but it does not differ a lot from what you have to do for desktop.